# Surface Internet Explorer 11 Javascript PointerEvents issue

Tags: javascript, touch, internet-explorer-11, pointer-events

I'm trying to do some experiment with Pointer API of Internet Explorer 11 on my Surface tablet, but I have some issues.

I do a Fiddle to explain better (please open the console to try) : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2w9S/)

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    function onEvent(e) {
        console.log(e.type + ' ' + e.pageX + '/' + e.pageY);
    }

    if (window.PointerEvent) {
        window.addEventListener('pointerdown', onEvent);
        window.addEventListener('pointerup', onEvent);
        window.addEventListener('pointerout', onEvent);
    } else if (window.MSPointerEvent) {
        window.addEventListener('MSPointerDown', onEvent);
        window.addEventListener('MSPointerUp', onEvent);
        window.addEventListener('MSPointerOut', onEvent);
    }
})();
```

If you put your finger on the Result area, the pointerdown event is fired with your finger position on the screen. Until here, all is well.

But, if you move your finger, the pointerout is fired mostly with the same position, sometimes with a different position and the pointerup is never fired.

I try the same code in another tablet with Windows 8.1 and Internet Explorer 11 and I have the same behavior.

Somebody have any idea about that?

Thank you.